# Wrong user agent detection the first time entering the websie

Tags: php, wordpress, user-agent

I have strange problem in my Wordpress site.
If someone enters the website from **mobile** device, the server serves the regular home page, than if the user refreshes the mobile site is loaded correctly.

In the desktop PC it shows the regular site as usual.

The way I load the mobile site is:

```php
<?php
/*
    Template Name: some_page
*/

$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry){
    include_once('mobile_page.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

any idea what could be possibly wrong?

Comment: Sounds a bit, like something else would react to cookies. That would be another part of the code, though.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to now what is contained in the HTTP_USER_AGENT when the mobile web page is not loaded. Also note that strpos can return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE even if the "needle" string is found. For example, if the "needle" is in the first part of the "haystack", strpos will return 0 indicating that the string was found starting at index 0 of "haystack". Probably not the issue here but...